# How do I create a table in a div from info submitted in a form?

Tags: mysql, forms, dynamic

I am looking to find a way of creating a table in a div from the information submitted by the user in a form.  The table would have a fixed number of columns, but a variable number of rows.

Would I be able to do this directly, or would the information need to be added to a mySQL database and then the table would be filled from the database on page reload?

Any information as to my options here would be helpful.

Comment: you'll be able to do it on client side too. using javascript. but you can save data to mysql, or process it in server code and return to reloaded page.

Comment: Thanks. So it can be done purely with javascript?  could this include an option to edit rows in the table after they have been created?

Comment: yes of course  but you'll lose all data after refreshing the page, so if you need it to be saved, u must store them in mysql.

Comment: oh, OK.  Thanks.  MySQL it is then.  And then what would be the best method of generating the table from the mySQL data, such that it could be edited?

Comment: you can save data with ajax request to DB. So user will edit table and MySQL will be updating without page reloads.

Comment: Thanks.  So, just to check I have the procedure correct.  I create a form which submits data to mySQL.  Then I populate and edit the table with ajax request to mySQL?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know JavaScript is meant to be client side therefore cannot directly help you with things you want to do on your server ! I dont know what platform you are using , but regardless, you need to have a serve-side code(e.g PHP, ASP, JSP ...) to make a db connection and create the table for you and optionally redirect to the same page or another. Basically it does not require any use of javascript code, except if you want to perform the action without reloading the page, In that case you need to use AJAX an I would suggest you to use jQuery AJAX functions.